# C# read unicode?

Tags: c#, unicode, stream, ascii

I am receiving a unicode message via the network, which looks like:

74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 3F 00

I am using a BinaryReader to read the stream from my socket, but the problem is that it doesn't offer a "ReadWideString" function, or something similar to it. Anyone an idea how to deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple!

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(array);
```

where `array` is your array of bytes.

Answer (score 8):

Strings in C# are Unicode by default.  Try

```
string converted = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
```

where data is a byte[] array containing your Unicode data.  If your data is big endian, you can try

```
string converted = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(data);
```

Comment: Each byte every 2 is equal to 0, it's rather unlikely that it's utf-8.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `StreamReader` like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
```

If your stream only contains lines of text then `StreamReader` is more suitable than `BinaryReader`. If your string is embedded inside binary data then it is probably better to decode the string using the `Encoding.GetString` method as others have suggested